# How to change the position of elements using ConstraintLayout Flow?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, androidx

Few days ago I want to customize a TabLayout like [this (RallyTab)](https://github.com/hashlin/rally#rallytab), which uses Flow and can rearrange the elements according to the clicked icon.

**I read its [source code](https://github.com/hashlin/rally/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/material/rally/ui/RallyTab.kt), and its function of rearranging elements seems to be achieved by the `ConstraintHelper.setReferencedIds(int[] ids)` on line 168.** But when I try the following code, it does not work:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Flow flow = findViewById(R.id.flow);
        int[] ids = new int[] {R.id.image1, R.id.image3, R.id.image2, R.id.image4, R.id.image5};
        flow.setReferencedIds(ids);
    });
```

This is layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/cl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
        android:id="@+id/flow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="image1, image2, image3, image4, image5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_exposure_neg_2_24" />
    
    <!-- image2, image3, image4, image5 are the same as image1, only the id and srcCompat are different -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Even if I copy its [source code](https://github.com/hashlin/rally/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/material/rally/ui/RallyTab.kt) and [layout xml](https://github.com/hashlin/rally/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/layout_rally_tab.xml) to my project, it still not work. When i clicked on its icon, the position of elements did not change, only the TextView was playing its beautiful animation.

So I realized that the `ConstraintHelper.setReferencedIds(int[] ids)` method does not change the position of elements (or it will, welcome to correct me :-)), and RallyTab may have called some method in somewhere that I did not notice to rearrange them.

How do I do to change the position of elements like RallyTab? Can anybody point out where I missed? Or what should I do to achieve this function without Flow? Thanks in advance.